# How could I skip over several elements in XML and get a set of specific attribute tags with XPath in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am building a dynamic parsing tool ment to grab the elements of a generated XML file. To do so, when the file is known I would usually grab the elements with xpath('//*[local-name() = "row"]'); However, I need to grab all of the "name" attributes AFTER "row", and I'm not having much luck on that. What should I do in order to successfully grab an attribute labeled "name"?

Sample XML:

```
<DataSet xmlns="***">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="RawData">
<xs:element name="RawData" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="row">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:attribute name="UID" msdata:DataType="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" type="xs:string"/>
```

The desired result would be to grab all of the "attribute - name=" under the last complexType.

Comment: Can you show some sample XML markup and the part you'd like to grab?

Comment: Edit that into the question, @Merlin. Also post the expected result.

Comment: Also, what do you mean with _after_? Do you mean a child (so after as seen in the hierarchy) or you mean after in a document sense (i.e. order of lines). Expected output would help, indeed. By the way, you can simply write `//*:row` instead of your local-name() construct. Also, normally you can grab an attribute simply by using `@name`

Comment: Okay, I guess I ment to say I want to grab all of the possible "name" elements within "row". The point is to be able to construct a foreach loop that will output all of the names.

Comment: *:row will not work, here is no such thing as a default or universal namespace selector in Xpath - only in CSS (*|row).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after an age: $return = $response->xpath('//*[local-name() = "attribute"]');

Answer (score 0):

You should not ignore the namespace, just register a prefix for it. It is always a better idea being specific. Because of the `xpath()` method, I assume you're using SimpleXML at the moment. It has some namespace handling but it is limited. If you use DOM it is a lot easier and less complex.

3 steps:

1. Create the DOM and load you XML (or HTML)
2. Create an Xpath instance and register the namespaces you need
3. Fetch the nodes using Xpath expressions

An example:

```
// create the DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);

// create an Xpath instance for the DOM and register namespace prefixes
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('data', '***');
$xpath->registerNamespace('xs', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
$xpath->registerNamespace('msdata', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata');

// fetch all attribute elements of the last xs:complexType in the DOM
$attributes = $xpath->evaluate('//xs:complexType[last()]/xs:attribute');

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
  var_dump(
    [
      // read an attribute without a namespace
      $attribute->getAttribute('name'),
      // read an attribute with a namespace independent of any namespace prefix
      $attribute->getAttributeNS(
        'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata', 'DataType'
      ),
      // fetch an attribute with a namespace using xpath
      $xpath->evaluate('string(@msdata:DataType)', $attribute, FALSE)
    ]
  );
}
```

Output: https://eval.in/140586

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "UID"
  [1]=>
  string(88) "System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
  [2]=>
  string(88) "System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
}
```

"last" is ambiguous. Do you mean the last `complexType` the document or the last of the `schema` children?